# how to put data from list to many2many

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to put data form list to many2many

```
@api.multi
def favorite_menus(self):
......
return popular_words[:3]
```

and I try to show as many2many field
(deta in popular_word is [a,b,c])

```
menu = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='lunch.order.line', default=lambda self:[self.favorite_menus()])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In odoo relation field accepts a list of command so if your list is a command list than i think it should be good:

default is used in create method :

to add record use 4 cammond your list should contains data like this :

command 4 tells odoo to add the id in the second place in the record list

```
      [(4, id), (4, id2), .......]
```

id is the ID of the record that you want to add as Integer value.

if you want to create a new records  use 0 command :

```
         [(0, 0, {'field_name': value_name, 'field_2': value_2 }) , ...]
```

Command 0 tells odoo to create a record from the dictionary in the last position

Tha you don't want default value instead you need a default domain:

```
menu = fields.Many2many(
    comodel_name='lunch.order.line',
    domain=lambda self:self.favorite_menus())

@api.multi
def favorite_menus(self):
    """ return a default domain."""
    # first calculate the list of the menu that you want
    # the user to select one of them i'm assuming that you use search
    # so the result is a recordSet of menu 
    menus = .....

    return "[('id', 'in', '%s')]" % (tuple(menus.ids), ) # keep the comma 
    # or try this i think bouth work
    return [('id', 'in', menus.ids)]
```

Note: you may need to change the domain to fit your needs.
      but to prevent the user from selecting other element you need to filter
      them use domain for that in m2m or o2m or m2o fields.

Comment: I add

 `return [(4, popular_menu) for popular_menu in popular_words[:3]]`

and

 `menu = fields.Many2many('lunch.order.line', default=lambda self:self.favorite_menus())`

it still show all data in database
how can i show only data in list?

Comment: What do you mean by showing is when you click on add item it shows you all the menu. Or when you create the record the many2many field os loaded with all records ?

Comment: I want to make function favorite things that means show most frequency on the wizard

`menu = fields.Many2many('lunch.order.line', default=lambda self:self.favorite_menus())`

is command in wizard.

sorry if I don't understand. I am very new in odoo.

Comment: Ok so when you the user click on add item you want only to see this list of menus so he can choose one or many

Comment: what the way can I create it??